# How to tell if two ethernet interfaces are on the same lan?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I have to secure interfaces on Linux servers by setting bonding interfaces. The cabling information is not accurate.

Is there a simple way to know if two interfaces are connected to the same LAN?

Some interfaces have no IP, if possible I would prefer to not set dummies IPs.

---

I finally did it using `arping`, it was already installed on the servers:

```
ifconfig eth2 up 
ifconfig ethO up 
tcpdump -i eth2 -c 3 arp net 10.10.10.10
```

and in another terminal :

```
arping -D -I eth0 10.10.10.10
```

`tcpdump` should displays lines like that:

```
16:15:43.032103 arp who-has 10.10.10.10 (Broadcast) tell 0.0.0.0
16:15:44.032277 arp who-has 10.10.10.10 (Broadcast) tell 0.0.0.0
16:15:45.032441 arp who-has 10.10.10.10 (Broadcast) tell 0.0.0.0
```

*`-D` is optional but it gives a nice 0.0.0.0 source address.

Comment: Try to send an arp broadcast message on one interface and see if you can see it on the other one

Comment: @UlrichDagel I didn't managed to specifically generate ethernet datagrams on one interface. Do you know a standard command to do that ?

Comment: you can either write your own tool or use somthing like scapy, arpscan etc and check in parallel with tcpdump on the other deice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some ideas, assuming interfaces are eth0 and eth1:

- Sniff on both interfaces at the same time for non unicast traffic. You should see all packets twice

  ```
  ( tcpdump -nni eth0 -c 10 broadcast or multicast & tcpdump -nni eth1 -c 10 broadcast or multicast & ) | sort
  ```
- Probe with an IP-less protocol.

  For example with this tool to generate DHCP requests:
  http://www.latinsud.com/pub/dhd/dhd.c

  ```
  ( sleep 1; ./dhd eth1 > /dev/null ) & tcpdump -nni eth0 udp and port 68
  ```

  You should see something like this:

  ```
  14:46:16.449738 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:50:56:99:76:cb, length 300
  14:46:16.650330 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:50:56:99:76:cb, length 300
  ```